# Does Rails automtically track the Date?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am making a `Calendar Model` for my `Product model` because i need a list of products to belong to only one Date whether past or present products. I want my users to be able to search for a specific date of a product when i put a search engine in and pagination. Is it a good idea to do this or is there a better way? Does Rails have a way to not make a model and still give many products one date?

Comment: Can you define what this date is, i.e. is it some domain-specific date, or just the date the record was created in the system?  For the later, each record (default) has a created_at timestamp when you include the t.timestamps call in the models creation migration.

Comment: OK, but i also give the users a choice to input a date for past or present. e.g. I bought cereal  in Jan 2010 then they can select that with the f.date_select field. Is their another way going about doing this without the need for a whole new Model because remember i need one list of products to belong to one date on the form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you wish to store something else in the Calendar model you should just store the date as a field of the products model. Then you can find_all_by_date.

Comment: I know i could do this but my goal here is to  give users the ability to create a List of Products with one date on the form and was thinking their was a cleaner solution.

Comment: Hi Justin. I don't understand the problem to be honest. Each product has a date. A user wishes to view all products of a date so selects a date from the form to the controller which performs a find_all_by_date on the product model.

Comment: Well, still a helpful answer because i didn't know about the find_by_date method. In future for my application i may also need a Calendar model, thanks for the clarification.

Comment: Note that find_by_date is dynamically created by active record when you add a date field. So for example if you had a doughnut column you would then have a find_by_doughnut method etc. As Colin Ross pointed out, you do have two default datetime fields, created_at and updated_at which might be enough if you find records within the range of each day.